# Meaning of square brackets, optional arguments

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

I'm a bit confused as to how LaTeX parses square brackets/optional macro arguments.

I'll try to explain what I understood by means of the macro `\section` which has one optional and one mandatory argument. Please correct me if you think I got anything wrong.

This

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\section ab
\end{document}
```

finds no optional argument, and a mandatory argument `a`. `b` is just text then. With `{}`, one can group things, so

```latex
\section {ab}
```

takes `ab` as mandatory argument. The space doesn't matter.

Square brackets `[]` usually get rendered as square brackets. Unless, it seems, if it *could* potentially contain optional arguments. This

```latex
\section[a]{b}
```

takes `a` as optional, `b` as mandatory argument. Are optional arguments always indicated by square brackets?

This

```latex
\section[a][b]{c}
```

takes `a` as optional argument, `[` as mandatory argument, and `b]{c}` is just text.

[image]

This, too, seems to indicate that square brackets are square brackets if and only if they aren't in their function of optional argument. Is this correct?

Comment: It depends. You can have macros that has two or more optional args in `[]`. Fx in the `memoir` class `\sectrion[a][b]{c}` works. In the standard class `\section` has one optional arg, here it found one and stops looking for more and then it take the next `[` as the value for the mandatory arg. Nowadays using `xparse` one can define al sorts of argument even optional `{}` arguments (which can be useful in some circumstances event if it is discouraged)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the command. The way arguments are parsed is command specific, not TeX/LaTeX imposed.

Some commands expect optional arguments and then parse the square brackets as the start of optional arguments. Other commands expect no optional arguments and then a square bracket is just an argument.

See these examples:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}


\NewDocumentCommand{\mycmd}{o o m}{\IfValueTF{#1}{first #1}{nothing on one},
  \IfValueTF{#2}{second #2}{nothing on two},
  mandatory #3}
\newcommand\anothercmd[1]{My argument is /#1/}

\begin{document}
\mycmd{Hello}

\mycmd[1]{Hello}

\mycmd[1][2]{Hello}

\anothercmd{test}

\anothercmd[2]{Test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good answer. Just so people remembers it, on modern LaTeX installations the line `\usepackage{xparse}` is not necessary. The functionality is now build into the kernel. But it does not hurt to have it there for users on old systems, or if one want to use the features from `xparse` what wasn't added to the kernel, eg the optional `{}` argument.